# Firebase HTTP function CORS issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I cannot get my Firebase http function working when calling it from the client. Here are the errors on the client:

```
OPTIONS https://us-central1-my-app.cloudfunctions.net/my-func 500 ()

Failed to load https://us-central1-my-app.cloudfunctions.net/my-func: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Here is what my function looks like:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

exports.func = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors((req, res, () => {
    res.send("hello");
  }));
});
```

The Firebase functions log is providing this information:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined
    at /user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:39
    at optionsCallback (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
    at corsMiddleware (/user_code/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
    at exports.pay.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/my-func.js:11:10)
```

Note that 11:10 in the call stack is this: `return cors((req, res, () => {`

The request I'm making is sending an object with a single key:value pair in the request body. I added the `cors` middleware based on other questions I've seen on SO, but no luck!

Edit: Adding the request code:

```
function post(url, obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    req.onload = function() {
      if(req.status == 200) {
        return resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        return reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    req.onerror = function() {
      return reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    req.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
  });
}
```

Comment: What does the full request look like?  Code for that?

Comment: @DougStevenson, added the code. I call the `post` method and pass in my URL and obj.

Comment: Multiple incidents may affect at present Cloud Functions for Firebase. Your issue might derive from this situation. You can follow developments on the [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) page.

Answer (score 9):

Programmer error, as usual:

```
cors((req, res, () => {
    res.send("hello");
  }));
```

should be:

```
cors(req, res, () => {
    res.send("hello");
  });
```

Had an extra set of parens around the `cors` args.